# Transpiling Javascript to Typescript. My built files are not ending up where I expected them

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, cypress

I am in the process of learning Cypress & Typescript. I have set up my files according to the following article:

[Converting a JavaScript project to Typescript, one file at a time](https://dev.to/suhas_chatekar/converting-a-javascript-project-to-typescript-one-file-at-a-time)

webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');


module.exports = {  
  mode: "development",
  entry: { 
    index: "./cypress/integration/alloy_test.ts"
  },
target: 'node',
  : {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts(x?)$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },      
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'})
    ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json']
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'lib'), 
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
};
```

Here is specified the directory /lib, which is where I expect all the generated Typescript files to go.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "lib": [
        "es5","es2015", "es6", "dom"
        ],
        "types": ["cypress"]
    }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "playground",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "build": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/prompt-sync": "^4.1.0",
    "cypress": "^3.1.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "ts-loader": "^5.2.2",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.0.0",
    "ajv-keywords": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.3"
  }
}
```

I am running npm run build to do the transpiling.

At then end, my one .ts file, /cypress/integration/alloy-test.ts - has been transpiled to the same directory: /cypress/integration/alloy-test.js.

I was expecting it to go to /lib.

Comment: What's the rest of your webpack config look like?

Comment: @Phix added webpack.config,js

Comment: Your webpack file is malformed, I'm guessing it's a copy-paste botch?

Comment: @SteveStaple Webpack shouldn't actually be producing transpiled JS files, its producing output JS bundles. Most likely you have a TSC process somewhere else that is doing the straight TS-to-JS transpilation... IDEs such as VSCode or Webstorm will often automatically pick up the TS config and start transpiling. Your TS config is using default output destination which is JS alongside TS files.

Comment: @Phix - my webpack is malformed - in what way?

Comment: Copy what you have above into a new file.

Comment: @Phix - what is the problem with my webpack.config.js?

Comment: @Aaron - that does not sound right. re: output in webpack.config.js -
This is where we tell webpack how do we want the output of the transpilation to appear. We are saying that we want the output files to be named after the key name we used for the file in the entry section. We want the output files to be copied into a folder named lib under the current directory. And we want webpack to use commonjs module system. https://dev.to/suhas_chatekar/converting-a-javascript-project-to-typescript-one-file-at-a-time

Comment: @SteveStaple Yes, that is what *Webpack* does (bundle into the specified `output` dir and naming), but `tsconfig.json` is also detected and used by `tsc` directly (try running `tsc` from command line), and the `tsconfig` you posted does not specify an `outDir` so TSC will output JS files alongside TS files in their current dirs. This is why I suspect there is a separate TSC process running somewhere. I've encountered this problem with IDEs running TSC many times. By habit I always set the `tsconfig` `outDir` to something like `./compiled` and ignore that dir from webpack and git.